# getting error Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.kohsuke.stapler:maven-stapler-plugin trying to build slideshow-plugin

Tags: jenkins-plugins

When i try to build (mvn) the slide-show plugin, i get error:
(see detaied stdout below)

mvn -e

```
+ Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] POM for 'org.kohsuke.stapler:maven-stapler-plugin:pom:1.15:runtime' is invalid.

Its dependencies (if any) will NOT be available to the current build.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error building POM (may not be this project's POM).


Project ID: org.kohsuke.stapler:maven-stapler-plugin
POM Location: /home/kahmed/.m2/repository/org/kohsuke/stapler/maven-stapler-plugin/1.15/maven-stapler-plugin-1.15.pom

Reason: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.kohsuke.stapler:maven-stapler-plugin at /home/kahmed/.m2/repository/org/kohsuke/stapler/maven-stapler-plugin/1.15/maven-stapler-plugin-1.15.pom


[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Unable to build project for plugin 'org.kohsuke.stapler:maven-stapler-plugin': Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.kohsuke.stapler:maven-stapler-plugin at /home/kahmed/.m2/repository/org/kohsuke/stapler/maven-stapler-plugin/1.15/maven-stapler-plugin-1.15.pom
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.loadPluginFully(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:1599)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.findArtifactTypeHandlersInPlugins(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:1468)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.findExtensions(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:222)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:178)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.InvalidPluginException: Unable to build project for plugin 'org.kohsuke.stapler:maven-stapler-plugin': Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.kohsuke.stapler:maven-stapler-plugin at /home/kahmed/.m2/repository/org/kohsuke/stapler/maven-stapler-plugin/1.15/maven-stapler-plugin-1.15.pom
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.checkRequiredMavenVersion(DefaultPluginManager.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.verifyVersionedPlugin(DefaultPluginManager.java:205)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.verifyPlugin(DefaultPluginManager.java:184)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.loadPluginFully(DefaultPluginManager.java:1626)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.loadPluginFully(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:1582)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.project.InvalidProjectModelException: Not a v4.0.0 POM. for project org.kohsuke.stapler:maven-stapler-plugin at /home/kahmed/.m2/repository/org/kohsuke/stapler/maven-stapler-plugin/1.15/maven-stapler-plugin-1.15.pom
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.readModel(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:1599)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.readModel(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:1571)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.findModelFromRepository(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:562)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.buildFromRepository(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:251)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultPluginManager.checkRequiredMavenVersion(DefaultPluginManager.java:277)
    ... 19 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1 second
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Apr 16 00:32:26 EDT 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/182M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Just built it fine with Maven 3.0.4. What is your Maven version (`mvn -V`) and what MAVEN_OPTS is set to (if to anything)? Did you try `mvn -up`?

Answer (score 2):

I am getting this too (although its for the akuma artifact) and can explain why, but have not yet found a good solution. Both define a parent POM and a new repo:

```
<parent>
  <groupId>org.kohsuke</groupId>
  <artifactId>pom</artifactId>
  <version>2</version>
</parent>

<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>m.g.o-public</id>
    <url>http://maven.glassfish.org/content/groups/public/</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
```

The URL for this glassfish maven repo gives a 301 to `https://maven.glass...` and for some reason, maven decides to download the body of that response as the POM. If you look in your `~/.m2/repository/org/kohsuke/pom/2/pom-2.pom`, you should see something like:

```
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/0.6.39</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Manually looking at the glassfish repo, I do not even see the desired parent POM (at this time).

I hope this helps. If you are able to figure it out, please post back as this is as far as I have gotten so far!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem also, with a different POM from another project, and I was attempting to build with Maven 3.X.  The simple solution was to install the most recent 2.X version of Maven.  After that, it built fine.  Being a Maven novice, It appears the URI format for REPOS differs between the 2 versions.

Simply install Maven 2.X (I used 2.2.1), and put it's "bin" directory first in your PATH env variable, and you should be good to go.